# how to map any integer to an index in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const Arr = [0, 1, 2];

for (var i = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER; i <= Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER; i += 1) { ... }
```

Need to correlate any given **i** to an appropriate index in **Arr**, so that

```
i=-3 => 0
i=-2 => 1
i=-1 => 2
i=0 => 0
i=1 => 1
i=2 => 2
i=3 => 0
i=4 => 1
i=5 => 2
```

... etc.

Comment: It would be more appropriate to use an object with 2 properties: the key and the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might recommend to make an `index` function that takes an array `xs`, and an index `i`. Conceptually, what we want to do is *wrap* `i` around if it goes out-of-bounds of `xs` in either direction. The [remainder (%) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) is just what we need for the job

```js
const index = (xs, i) =>
  i < 0
    ? xs [0 - (i % xs.length)]
    : xs [i % xs.length]

const data =
  [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]

for (let i = -5; i < 6; i++)
  console.log (i, index (data, i))
// -5 'c'
// -4 'b'
// -3 'a'
// -2 'c'
// -1 'b'
// 0 'a'
// 1 'b'
// 2 'c'
// 3 'a'
// 4 'b'
// 5 'c'
```

Answer (score 2):

This question does not need the array factor. It is about mapping any integer to a limited range.

This you can do with the following transformation:

```
j = i - Math.floor(i/3)*3
```

NB: for positive numbers you could use just `i % 3`, but it does not give the results you desire for negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I've found quite a nice solution to this:

```
function mod(n, m) {
  const q = n % m;
  return q < 0 ? q + m : q;
}
```

found here: https://github.com/oliviertassinari/react-swipeable-views/blob/master/packages/react-swipeable-views-core/src/mod.js